# Mounting EKS EFS CSI Times Out before Pod Comes Up

Tags: kubernetes

I am using EKS with Kubernetes version 1.15 and when I create a Storageclass, Persistent-Volume, Persistent-Volume-Claim, and Deployment the pod fails with:

```
Warning  FailedAttachVolume  71s (x2 over 3m11s)  attachdetach-controller              AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "efs-pv" : attachment timeout for volume fs-<volume>
Warning  FailedMount         53s (x2 over 3m8s)   kubelet, ip-<ip-address>.ec2.internal  Unable to mount volumes for pod "influxdb-deployment-555f4c8b94-mldfs_default(2525d10b-e30b-4c4c-893e-10971e0c683e)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "default"/"influxdb-deployment-555f4c8b94-mldfs". list of unmounted volumes=[persistent-storage]. list of unattached volumes=[persistent-storage]
```

However when I try the same without building the Persistent-Volume it is successful, and creates its own that seemingly skips CSI. This is what I am working with:

deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: influxdb-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: influxdb
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: influxdb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: influxdb
        image: influxdb:1.7.10-alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8086
        volumeMounts:
        - name: persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/influx
      volumes:
      - name: persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: efs-claim
```

storageclass.yaml:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
reclaimPolicy: Retain
```

persistent-volume.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: efs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: fs-<volume-id>
```

persistent-volume-claim.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: efs-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Any idea on what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is something unclarified in aws EKS documents, but a must-do when you are going to use storageclass as first time setting.

EKS has no default storage class to be set up

I didn't work on EFS with EKS before, but does set with gp2 (EBS) with below yaml file successfully.

Paste here for your reference

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: gp2
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  fsType: ext4
```

Reference link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/storage-classes.html

Comment: Does this use the "in-tree" volumes instead of CSI?